# For what values of $x$ in $[0,2π]$ does the graph of $y=\cos{x}/(\sqrt{3}+\sin{x})$ have a horizontal tangent?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

> For what values of $x$ in $[0,2π]$ does the graph of $y=\cos{x}/(\sqrt{3}+\sin{x})$ have a horizontal tangent? List the values of $x$ below.

I solved the problem and at last it came out like $\sin{x}=-1/\sqrt{3}$. What will be the different values of $x$ since $\arcsin(-1/\sqrt{3})$ cannot be obtained.

Comment: *[Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)* is some MathJax tutorial.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Do you mean $y=\cos{x} + \sqrt{3}\sin{x}$?

Comment: umm...its not what i was asking about...and thanks

Comment: its (cosx)/(sqrt3+sinx)

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsin%28-1%2Fsqrt%283%29%29) can find $\arcsin \frac {-1}{\sqrt 3}$ with no problem, about $-0.61548$ radians

Comment: but there are two values of x..

Comment: That is fine.  The Alpha solution is outside your range, too.  You need to consider the periodicity of the trig functions to find the solutions in your range.  We (arbitrarily) restrict the values of $\arcsin$ to $[-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2]$ so it is single valued.  For many applications you want some of the other values.

Comment: so what do we need to do now? i entered the value -0.61548 and the ans is incorrect

Comment: That is because you asked for solutions in $[0, 2\pi]$ which this is not.  You need to transform this answer to the ones in your range.  As all the trig functions have a period $2 \pi$, adding that should give you one of the two solutions.  If you plot the graph of $\sin x$ you should be able to find another angle within your range that has this value.

Comment: ok thanks for your help:)